# How to switch between text styles using arrow keys?

Tags: java, applet

I'm creating a menu for my program. I'm trying to make the option they currently have to be in bold text so the user knows which one they are selecting.

I've imported java.applet.Applet, java.awt, and java.awt.event. I'm also using multiple classes. Here is the code I'm thinking where my issue is.

The first class

```
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
{

if (e.getKeyCode() ==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        classB.option1(true);
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() ==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        classB.option2(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the second class

```
public void move(Graphics g)
{
    if (option1 = true)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font ("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString("OPTION 1", 453, 380);
        g.setFont(new Font ("Century Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g.drawString("OPTION 2", 425, 415);
    }
    else if (option2 = true)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font ("Century Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g.drawString("OPTION 1", 453, 380);
        g.setFont(new Font ("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString("OPTION 2", 425, 415);
    }
    else if (!option1 && !option2)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font ("Century Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g.drawString("OPTION 1", 453, 380);
        g.setFont(new Font ("Century Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g.drawString("OPTION 2", 425, 415);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having right now is that none of this displays, even if I press the arrow keys.

Thanks.

Comment: as far as i know, classB.option1(true); this line should mean you are calling method option1 in class B o.O

Comment: to set option1 in class B as true i would do classB.option1=true;

Answer (score 2):

```
if (option1 = true)
```

should be

```
if (option1 == true)
```

The same goes for the option 2 if!